# Flutter & Push Notification : Is there a way to turn off push notification?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, onesignal

Flutter & Push Notification : Is there a way to turn off push notification?

So I want to give my app this ability to turn on and off the push notification.
FYI, I am using OneSignal.
Could you tell a function to do that? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read One Signal documentation, and it said that android devices are subscribed to notifications automatically when the app is installed. You can create and customize a "soft-prompt" to ask users to grant push permission multiple times.

See: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-push-opt-in-prompt